# Why does ordering by factor destroy the decimal places

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am try to do a simple ggplot of my dataframe

```
  structure(list(CLevel = c(3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11), 
 Sensitivity = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 8L, 9L), 
.Label = c("56.6666666666667","53.125", "52.9411764705882", "52.9411764705882", 
"54.2857142857143", "54.2857142857143", "55.5555555555556", "56.7567567567568",
 "57.1428571428571"), class = "factor"), 
Specificity = c(76.4705882352941, 76.4705882352941, 76.4705882352941, 76.4705882352941,
 76.4705882352941, 76.4705882352941, 76.4705882352941,
 76.4705882352941, 76.4705882352941)), 
 .Names = c("CLevel", "Sensitivity", "Specificity"), row.names = c(NA, -9L),
 class ="data.frame")
```

When I do the plot as follows

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot() + 
  geom_point(aes(CLevel, Sensitivity, color = "red",size=12), St) +  
  geom_point(shape=5)
```

I get an x axis which is not ordered the way I want.

So than I tried

```
St$Sensitivity <- factor(St$Sensitivity, levels = St$Sensitivity[order(St$CLevel)])
```

but I get the error

```
In `levels<-`(`*tmp*`, value = if (nl == nL) as.character(labels) else paste0(labels,  : duplicated levels in factors are deprecated
```

So I looked at my data frame again and it looks as though there are duplicates in the Sensitivity column because the decimal point has been stripped off so some of the numbers are exactly the same. All I want to do is order the x axis so this seems unnecessarily complicated. How can I do this?

Comment: Do you really want Sensitivity to be a factor? It looks like a double.

Comment: When you say your x-axis isn't ordered the way you want, do you mean the y-axis?

Comment: Also, how _do_ you want the axis to be ordered?

Comment: I wanted the axis to be ordered by C level

Comment: Which axis do you want ordered by `CLevel`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change Sensitivity to a double, the resulting plot looks appropriate:

```
St <- structure(list(CLevel = c(3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11),

               Sensitivity = c(56.6666666666667, 53.125, 52.9411764705882,
                 52.9411764705882, 54.2857142857143, 54.2857142857143,
                 55.5555555555556, 56.7567567567568, 57.1428571428571 ),

               Specificity = c(76.4705882352941, 76.4705882352941,
                 76.4705882352941, 76.4705882352941, 76.4705882352941,
                 76.4705882352941, 76.4705882352941, 76.4705882352941,
                 76.4705882352941)),

          .Names = c("CLevel", "Sensitivity", "Specificity"),
          row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = "data.frame")  

library(ggplot2)
ggplot() + 
  geom_point(aes(CLevel, Sensitivity, color = "red",size=12), St) +  
  geom_point(shape=5)
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
 ## to avoid typing "Sensitivity" so many times:
 s <- levels(St$Sensitivity) 
 St2 <- transform(St,Sensitivity=factor(Sensitivity,
                         levels=s[order(as.numeric(s))]))
 library("ggplot2")
 ggplot(St2,aes(CLevel,Sensitivity))+
     geom_point(color = "red",size=12, shape=5)
```

Note that I put the colour, size, and shape specifications *outside* of the mapping (`aes()`) specification, which I'm guessing is what you actually wanted ...

As @VeerendraGadekar says, the warnings occur because the values you gave us do indeed have duplicates in the factor levels.  In particular, quoting directly from the structure you gave us (just rearranging the spacing slightly for clarity)

```
.Label = c("56.6666666666667",
           "53.125", 
           "52.9411764705882",
           "52.9411764705882", ## duplicate
           "54.2857142857143", 
           "54.2857142857143", ## duplicate
           "55.5555555555556", 
           "56.7567567567568", 
           "57.1428571428571")
```

Perhaps you lost precision somewhere upstream?

Answer (score 0):

**Edited:**

I see the levels are *characters* avoid using `""` when you are using numbers

This should be the appropriate sample data

```
St =  structure(list(CLevel = c(3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11), Sensitivity = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 8L, 9L), .Label = c(56.6666666666667,53.125, 52.9411764705882, 52.9411764705882, 54.2857142857143, 54.2857142857143, 55.5555555555556, 56.7567567567568, 57.1428571428571), class = "factor"), Specificity = c(76.4705882352941, 76.4705882352941, 76.4705882352941, 76.4705882352941, 76.4705882352941, 76.4705882352941, 76.4705882352941, 76.4705882352941, 76.4705882352941)), .Names = c("CLevel", "Sensitivity", "Specificity"), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class ="data.frame")
```

you can try ordering like this

```
ggplot() + 
geom_point(aes(CLevel, reorder(Sensitivity, -as.vector(Sensitivity)), color = "red",size=12), St) + 
geom_point(shape=5)

# or use this: reorder(Sensitivity, as.vector(Sensitivity)) based on your requirement
```

required

[image]

Comment: This gives me 18 warnings, including the ones already mentioned by the OP.

Comment: @AlexA. I edited the answer, however we can still see the warnings like `duplicated levels in factors are deprecated` which are because of the duplicated levels for the factor